# Loading and executing .el file if it exists on startup

Tags: init-file, load

I am having trouble telling Emacs to load and evaluate an additional .el file which only contains some lisp code to load an org file

```
;; keep my personal settings not in the .emacs file
;; http://www.mygooglest.com/fni/dot-emacs.html
;; load it if it exists
(let ((personal-settings "~/personal.el"))
 (when (file-exists-p personal-settings)
   (load-file personal-settings))
)
```

If I call the file `personal.el` interactively via `load-file` Emacs executes the code (which just contains some lisp code to load an org file).

If I run `M-X eval-buffer` on the .emacs manually, the `personal.el` is executed properly, the org file is loaded.

What do I need to do to make Emacs load the file if it exists during emacs start?

**EDIT**

I rephrased the question and ran additional tests: `(expand-file-name)` did not have any effect but more weird is that Emacs does not evaluate a hard-coded `(find-file "~/Dropbox/orgmode.org")` even if it is the only line in my .emacs file. And again it works if I load this file manually and run `m-x eval-buffer` on it.

Comment: You're missing a question: your description basically says that if you load the file it works.  Great, so what's the problem?

Comment: What @Stefan said. Also, you might want to consider putting the file in a directory in your `load-path` and using `require` or `load-library`.

Comment: Does it work if you call (expand-file-name) before calling load-file?  The ~ may need to be substituted.

Answer (score 2):

Mystery solved, it's a bit embarrassing: Emacs is doing fine but just showing the startup-screen as first buffer. Disabling it via `(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)?` does the trick...